# Distribution of maximum variance explained by 1 variable

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, joint-distribution, multivariate-regression, extreme-value

Say I do principal component analysis on $n$ variables, and I sort the fractions of variance explained to find the largest. What is the probability distribution for this figure?

For context I just did this with 736 variables, found the maximum was 0.29, thought, "That sounds like a lot for such a large $n$", and then thought, "But is it?" So of course, a large-$n$ approximation would be illuminating.

My guess is that, because the $n$ fractions sum to $1$, they have an approximately Dirichlet distribution, [but that doesn't help much](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236754/maximum-of-a-probability-vector-distributed-as-a-dirichlet-variate) unless the distribution's $\alpha$ simplifies the problem. I'd imagine each $\alpha_i$ is equal to $1$ for this problem.

Comment: This paper I think, has _**exactly**_ what you're looking for - [On the distribution of the largest eigenvalue in principal components analysis, Iain M. Johnstone, 2001](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1009210544)

Comment: Asking for a probability distribution implies you are viewing at least one of the $n$ variables as being a random variable.  The answer depends on what you assume the distribution of those original variables is.  What are you assuming?